# HTML5 footer tag

Tags: css, html

I'm building this site and I have a problem with my footer. I want the dark green color in the footer to cover up the whole footer. but know it only covers for a height of 10px or something like that instead for +- 200px. What am I doing wrong?

Link to my site: http://bit.ly/LSVux5 but I want it to look like this http://bit.ly/LSW3Hn

the color does not matter, only the zone that covers it

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Add `overflow:hidden;` to the `#footer-container` rules. The floating elements cause the footer to act like it has no content, the overflow property will fix that.

Comment: Heres some more information about enclosing floats: http://gtwebdev.com/workshop/floats/enclosing-floats.php

Answer (score 2):

**[Working Version](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/Fu2Ax/)**

You just need to clear your floats, you can do that by changing your footer to the following.

```
  <footer class="wrapper clearfix">
```

Just add the `clearfix` class (which is already declared in your style sheet) to your footer.

Comment: This answer uses multiple classes on a single element, which is cool. This should be the chosen answer.